# HTML/Javascript: Trigger 2 different action from 1 button

Tags: javascript, html

How can we trigger 2 action from 1 button? How do we make a button/or links which can go/scroll to element "#result" and trigger the function "calculateThis" (proceed data from a form)

How do I mix the these into 1 button/link?

```
 <a href="#result">Submit</a>
```

and

```
 <button class="button" onclick="calculateThis(this.form); return false;">Submit</button>
```

// UPDATED
Here is the complete code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function calculateThis(form) {
var userweight=parseInt(form.weight.value, 10);
var caffeineamount=parseInt(form.caffein.value, 10);
var caffeinetimes=parseInt(form.caffeintimes.value, 10);
var totalcaffeine=caffeineamount*caffeinetimes;

console.log(totalcaffeine)
// Calculate max caffeine per person
var maxcaffeine=userweight*10;

// Calculate remaining after 24 hours
// Half life = 6 hours
var totalcaffeineafter=totalcaffeine*(1/16);

// Calculating how many hours until the caffeine completely digested
var totaldigest=totalcaffeine;
var digesttime=0;

while (totaldigest>0.05) {
totaldigest=totaldigest*(1/2);
digesttime++;
}

digesttime=digesttime*6;

// Calculating when the user will probably die of overdose
var countcaffeine=0;
var overdosetime=1;

while (countcaffeine<maxcaffeine){
countcaffeine=countcaffeine+totalcaffeine;
overdosetime++;
}

// Show total amount of caffeine
document.getElementById("showtotalkafein").innerHTML=totalcaffeine;

// Show amount of caffeine after 1 day
document.getElementById("showtotalkafeinsetelah").innerHTML=totalcaffeineafter;

// Show digest time
document.getElementById("showwaktudigest").innerHTML=digesttime;

// Show overdose
document.getElementById("showberapakali").innerHTML=overdosetime;

return false;
}
</script>

<form class="form">
Weight<br />
<input type="text" name="weight" class="required" value="" /><p /> 
Amount of caffein in coffee<br />
<input type="text" name="caffein" class="required" value="" /><p /> 
How many times drinking coffeein a day<br />
<input type="text" name="caffeintimes" class="required" value="" /><p />
<a href="#result" onClick="calculateThis(this.form); return false;">Submit</a>
</form>
<br />&nbsp;<br />&nbsp;<br />&nbsp;<br />&nbsp;<br />&nbsp;<br />&nbsp;<br />&nbsp;<br />&nbsp;<br />&nbsp;<br />&nbsp;<br />&nbsp;<br />&nbsp;<br />&nbsp;<br />&nbsp;<br />&nbsp;<br />&nbsp;<br />&nbsp;<br />&nbsp;<br />&nbsp;<br />&nbsp;<br />&nbsp;<br />&nbsp;<br />&nbsp;<br />&nbsp;<br />&nbsp;<br />&nbsp;<br />

<h1 id="result">Result</h1>
<p id="showtotalkafein">Show Caffein Total Here</p> 
<p id="showtotalkafeinsetelah">Show Caffeine Amount After 24 hours</p> 
<p id="showwaktudigest">Show Digest Time Here</p> 
<p id="showberapakali">Show Overdose Time Here</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do the same as in the button, i.e

```
<a href="#result" onClick="calculateThis(this.form); return false;">Submit</a>
```

Doesn't this work?

Comment: It does make us go to the element #result, but it does not process the function "calculateThis" :(

Answer (score 0):

JaggenSWE's answer is almost there, but don't return false since this suppresses default behaviour, which is to follow the link.

```
<a href="#result" onClick="calculateThis(this.form);">Submit</a>
```

I wouldn't advise using inline event handlers though.

**Edit**

This works. http://jsbin.com/uwatab/3/

Its always preferable to attach an onsubmit handler to a form, rather than button onclick. This way, pressing enter in your form still executes your javascript.

Comment: It does make us go to the element #result, but it does not process the function "calculateThis" :(

Comment: no, it does not says that there is any error w/ the javascript :/

Comment: Does your button object have a form property?

Comment: Yes it does :)  
I have updated the question with a complete code  .
  
I've tried   <a href="#result"><button class="button" onclick="calculateThis(this.form); return false;">Submit</button></a> but it does not give the result I wanted

Comment: By default, `a` elements don't have `form` properties. Try `this.parentNode`

Comment: Oh maybe they do. Seems like everything in form has a form property. Cool. Does console.log log anything?

Comment: @vinc Why are you adding a `button` element, to it all from the `a`.  The button will submit the form, so the page will reload.